# How to remove duplication in arrays? (not turn unique, but remove the next value) PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, duplicate-data

I'll try to be very specific. Look, I have an input that sends an array:

```
echo "<input type='hidden' name='valortot[]'  class='valor$rowid' disabled>";
```

Once I click in a radio button the disable is removed and the value is set:

Radio button:

```
<input  class='radio$rowid'  name='".$codintercot."[]' value='$mpreco' type='radio' onclick='calcval($rowid,$valortot)'>
```

`$rowid` is the id of each row and `$valortot` is the value got by javascript and once clicked is insert in the hidden input.

The Javascript:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

             function calcval(valor,valortot){

                var valortot = valortot;
                var rowid = valor;
                var calcval = document.getElementsByClassName("valor"+rowid);

                for(var i = 0; i < calcval.length; i++) {
                    calcval[i].value=valortot;
                    calcval[i].disabled = false;
                }


             }
```

My problem is, when I send the array they're copied, duplicates can exist, like 2 itens with the same value, but not a copy next the value like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 2.44 [1] => 2.44 [2] => 3.7 [3] => 32.92 [4] => 32.92 )
```

It's odd, 2.44 and 32.92 were copied but not 3.7, how can I skip clones?

**EDIT:**

Oh I fould, I was enabling 3 at same time while I should just enable 1. But still thank you guys.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
<?php
    $input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
    $result = array_unique($input);
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Javascript, you can always use .indexOf(value).

```
for(var i = 1; i < array.length(); i++){
    if(array.indexOf(value) == -1) {
        array.push(value);
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
}
```

Now you wouldn't need the else statement, but it's there to give you the idea. Also, start the loop at 1 so that if the array is at element 0 (aka empty) if won't bother checking for duplicate results.

Good luck!

Edit - Wrong logic.